# Xamarin Studio not saving XAML files

Tags: xaml, xamarin, save

I'm working on a Mac with Xamarin Studio on a Xamarin.Forms project. For some reason, all my other files (including xaml.cs files) are being saved. But for some reason, all of my xaml files don't save my changes. I've tried right clicking and opening it in finder, and that file doesn't have the changes that I just made.

UPDATE: I never got a real solution. I just resorted to editing those xaml files in a separate editor.

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue today using the Xamarin Android Designer on VS to edit an .axml file. The changes don't save when closing the file. I'm able to edit the code and save changes, but I'd love to be able to use the editor...

Comment: Same issue here. It's very frustrating...

Comment: Same issue.. I'd suggest right clicking the file and opening it with the source editor instead of the layout editor. The source editor doesn't appear to have this problem.